# cannot modify asp login in page_load or page_init

Tags: asp.net, authentication, page-lifecycle

So I have an asp:Login field on my login page.

However, I want to use a path for the create account url and the forgot password url. So I have to do it in Page_Load or maybe Page_Init. Regardless, neither option works, it simply refuses to modify the login form.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string accountpath = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "/user/RequestAccount.aspx";
      string forgotpath = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "/user/ForgotPassword.aspx";
      lgnMain.CreateUserUrl = accountpath;
      lgnMain.PasswordRecoveryUrl = forgotpath;
      lgnMain.InstructionText = "test";
      lgnMain.Focus();
  }
  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

      string accountpath = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "/user/RequestAccount.aspx";
      string forgotpath = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "/user/ForgotPassword.aspx";
      lgnMain.CreateUserUrl = accountpath;
      lgnMain.UserName = "test";
      lgnMain.InstructionText = "test";
      lgnMain.PasswordRecoveryUrl = forgotpath;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateUserUrl` and the `PasswordRecoveryUrl` are ignored if you haven't set the `CreateUserText` and `PasswordRecoveryText` properties respectively. Since the Text properties probably don't need to be dynamic, just set them in the ASPX (although you could still set them in the code behind if required), and then the dynamic setting of the URL properties (in the `Page_Load` event) should work without problem.

Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login_members(v=vs.85).aspx

From the Documentation above:

> If the CreateUserText property is
> empty, the link to the registration
> page is unavailable to the user.
>
> If the PasswordRecoveryText property
> is empty, the link to the password
> recovery page is not available to the
> user.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setting it in the markup?

```
                   <asp:Login id="lgnMain" runat="server" 
                        CreateUserText="Register"
                        CreateUserUrl="~/user/RequestAccount.aspx"
                        PasswordRecoveryText = "Forgot Password"
                        PasswordRecoveryUrl = "~/user/ForgotPassword.aspx" >
                    </asp:Login>
```

Comment: This works fine. However, there is still a problem. See I have two IIS servers. The one on localhost, has a url like localhost/user/RequestAccount.aspx ---however, the website has like domain.com/virtualdir/user/RequestAccount.aspx. When I use ~/, it goes to domain.com/user/RequestAccount.aspx instead of domain.com/virtualdir/user/RequestAccount.aspx. See the problem?? I need a way to get the URL from the browser address bar in order to make sure that 'virtualdir' which is an IIS setting virtual dir, doesn't get ignored.

Comment: @Dexter what happens when you skip the `~` and use `"/user/RequestAccount.aspx"`  ?

Comment: @SOE it goes to domain.com/user/RequestAccount.aspx, even though I'm at the page domain.com/VirtualDir/login.aspx. I just want it to go to domain.com/VirtualDir/user/RequestAccount.aspx, I don't understand why just /user/RequestAccount.aspx doesn't work.

Comment: @Dexter I'm not sure then. That could be another question on stackoverflow by itself.

Comment: HMmm, how would I phrase it. I am having trouble explaining this problem to people because usually /user/RequestAccount works in most servers, especially apache. IIS just sux.

Comment: @Dexter just mention using `CreateUserUrl="~/user/RequestAccount.aspx"` goes to `domain.com/user/RequestAccount.aspx` instead of `domain.com/virtualdir/user/RequestAccount.aspx` and mention the directory structure you have in your web app.